styling of pmtiles in openlayers
Im quite a newbie on OL.
First, I downloaded a osm/NatEarth pre-built tile Dataset at https://maps.protomaps.com/builds/
after that, i created my local ol Project.
I saw, that the pmtiles styling may be handled by a local json like
https://maps.protomaps.com/#map=0.41/0/0&theme=light&lang=en&tiles=https://demo-bucket.protomaps.com/v4.pmtiles
I tried the ol-mapbox-style Module, but also it was not quite clear to me, how to incldue the Json Style (and maybe additional ressources like Fonts and so on) into the project.
and here comes my question:
what modules do i require (other than ol-pmtiles, ol/layer/VectorTile)
to use such a json AND how do i include that into my OL Project? (e.g. main.js)
The Documentation is not quite clear to me..
Thanks in advance

Try creating the layer (without a style) then applying the style (and background if necessary) from the style json as in https://openlayers.org/en/main/examples/vector-tiles-4326.html  If the pmtiles use a standard tile grid you probably do not need to specify resolutions, but you might need updateSource: false, see https://github.com/openlayers/ol-mapbox-style?tab=readme-ov-file#parameters-6

Thanks!
the source somehow does not load well(i think the gl tries some kind of tms schema)
+i get the following after npm start:
'No map visible because the map container's width or height are 0.'
my main.js looks like this:
'const layer = new VectorTileLayer({
declutter: true,
source: new VectorTileSource({
projection: 'EPSG:4326'
}),
});
applyStyle(layer, "data/style.json", {updateSource: false});
useGeographic();
const map = new Map({
target: "map",
layers: [layer],
view: new View({
center: [172.606201,-43.556510],
zoom: 7,
}),
});'

Have you set a size for the target div in css?
